# Reports Builder 10g: Memory issue with image links?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

throwing a hail mary here because I couldn't find any answers for this.

I have a Reports Builder 10g project where I have multiple image file links. I was able to successfully link the first 8 images, but get the following errors on the next image link:

```
REP-0069: Internal error
REP-62203: Internal error reading the image - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
```

and this error after I close that dialog box

```
REP-1800: Formatter error.
```

I believe this might be a memory issue, because I added up the linked image sizes, which totalled to ~9MB. I noticed that I could still link small images. I have a feeling the limit might be 10MB.

I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue and how you resolved it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're right when saying that it is the size limit problem.

I've had a report which - at the bottom of every page - printed someone's signature (it was  .JPG file). If there weren't many pages, the report was created successfully. However, when there were many pages, there was an error.

My "solution" was to load that .JPG file into an image editor and made it smaller (say, from 100 kB to 5 kB). You know how it goes ... someone signs on a paper, scans it and that's it. Who cares about the size? In my case, it was an easy task (just for information, if you're interested, I used *paint.net* to do that as it shows the target file size when saving a new .JPG, depending on image quality).

I don't know whether you can affect those images or not. If there are many of them, huh, you (or someone else) would have a lot to do. Besides, not all images can be resized and keep the quality. Basically, *it depends*.

Good luck!

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one to have this issue. I can't make the image smaller  because the image is the entire page, and and I'm just adding fields on top of it.

Comment: Not smaller in its dimensions (meaning: now it is 1000 x 500 pixels and you'd make it 100 x 50), but in bytes (now it is 100 kB, you'd make it 10 kB). How? As I said, in paint.net go to Save As, choose JPG, set quality to - for example - 70% and you'll see the new image size (will be 74 kB) so set the quality even lower to 40% and image size will now be 18 kB (these are NOT real figures! I used them just as example). Make a compromise between quality and size. If image shows a forest, you don't care about quality, it'll look more or less the same. If there are people, well ... see for yourself

Comment: I can't quite do that because they are images of forms, and I'm just adding fields over them. I tried compressing the jpg files, but after attaching a few of them,I get this error when I attach any more of them `REP-0606: Unable to read link file <filename here>. Check link format`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any other ideas. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.